# How does Google App Engine's load-balancer work?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm planning to build a web service on GAE that I anticipate having to deal with significant amounts of load.  I therefore want to make full use of memcache such that hopefully, most requests won't need to go to the datastore.

There will be several different users of this web service, and each one is likely to require different, and not-overlapping data from the datastore.  My hope is that GAE's load balancing will tend to send requests from the same user to the same Google App Engine instance, which will increase the memcache hit-rate.

Is this how the load balancer works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wether or not that is how the scheduling algorithms work, it is memcached job to show the same data to *all* instances, so if you cache your data on instance-A it will be available from instance-B.

This is the difference between memcached and just storing data in your app's memory.

Comment: Ah, interesting - so does memcached push all cached data to all instances?  That may not be ideal in my situation, as it would be useful if different instances could "specialize"

Comment: The way to think about it is that all instances share a single memcache server (in reality it's not that simple but you can think of it this way).

Comment: Right, but that doesn't really answer my question.  I need to know whether there is any ability for app engine instances to "specialize" based on the user.  I know that in a lot of applications the load balancer will try to send the same user to the same webnode, because its likely to have already cached the stuff that that user needs.

Comment: The basic answer is; No GAE won't allow you any control over where traffic gets routed and you shouldn't assume that user-A will repeatedly get routed to the same instance for any reason. You should easily be able to design your application to allow *any* instance to effectively serve cached content, this is precisely  the goal of distributed-memcache services.

Comment: The issue is not whether any instance *can* serve cached content, the issue is maximizing the cache-hit ratio by permitting the memcached instances on different webnodes to "specialize" for different users.